# Ambiguous use of subscript after update Xcode to 7.3 in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After update Xcode to 7.3 I get 3 errors in my code. Spendet houers for resolve it... I dont know anymore. In simulation-mode work everything fine, but if I want compile the app for the device I always get 3 errors:

Ambiguous use of subscript. Get the errors inside the both foreach :( PLEASE anybody help....

Here is the code:

```
var citiesNamesArray = [String]()

var citiesIDsArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

let savedCitiesList =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("citiesListArray")! as NSArray

for each in savedCitiesList {
    citiesNamesArray.append(each[1] as! String)
      citiesIDsArray.append(each[0] as! String)
}

for each in savedCitiesList {
       cityArray.append(City(cityId: each[0] as! String, cityName: each[1] as! String ))
  }

 }
```

Comment: If I copy this code into a Playground and muck with a few things to get it to compile (e.g. remove `override` and call to `super` because it's a top level function in the Playground) I have no compiler problems.

Comment: `if let savedCitiesList =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("citiesListArray") as? [[String]]`

Comment: BTW You can't save array of tuples to NSUserDefaults. Save it as a 2D array

Comment: The problem is that `savedCitiesList` is an NSArray, so Swift has no idea what types are in the array. This means that `each` will be `AnyObject` and `AnyObject` can't be sub scripted. You need to downcast `each as? SomeClass`

Comment: THX to Leo Dabus. It solved my problem!!!!